# Map keys sorting

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm building object-system for my application. Now I have such code:

```
std::map<std::string, Object*> mObjects;
```

The idea is to update each object of class `Object` (call `update`) but in some order.

There is a member `int z_index;` in each object. How can I sort the map due to that index (btw, indexes could be same)?

My first idea was: add id into the key name like:

```
Object *temp = /* ... */
temp->z_index = 5;
temp->name = "test";
mObjects[temp->z_index + temp->name] = temp;
```

But with this code I've lost accessing objects by name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like an ideal candidate for the boost multi-index container!

Or, you could maintain two maps, one by name one by index, both holding pointer to the same object (should look at smart pointers by the way - such as `shared_ptr`!)

Or create a more complex key (i.e. a `struct` with the name and index, provide `operator<`) which can check both the name and the index etc.

Comment: may be `std::multiset` also could be an option.

Comment: @Naveen, do you mean `std::multimap`?

Comment: @Naveen: None of the STL containers support simultaneous sorting predicates. Boost Multi-Index is the best choice if OP doesn't want to maintain 2 containers.